# Deleting item and reinserting them , is there a better way?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

in an existing application, I need to perform a post on a product item and update/add some related entities accordingly. It's code that was just present and the schema il widely used but I don't like it really.. maybe you can help me to understand if it's correct or if there's a better way of doing that.

```cs
var product = await _productRepository.TrackingQueryableSelect(f => f.Id == request.Id,
        i => i.ProductCategories,
        i => i.GuidePrices,
        i => i.ProductWebSiteMappings,
        i => i.ProductAssociatedProducts).SingleAsync(ct)
```

This retrieves the product and the related entities that will be erased, then reinserted from the model passed to the `UpdateAsync` method

down in the code there are those lines of code

```cs
if (request.Categories is { Count: > 0 })
{
    product.ProductCategories.ToList().ForEach(async x => await _productCategoryRepository.DeleteAsync(x, ct));


    //_productCategoryRepository.DeleteAll(product.ProductCategories.ToList());
    product.ProductCategories = request.Categories.Select(s => new ProductCategory()
    {
        CategoryId = s,
        DisplayOrder = 1
    }).ToList();
}

if (request.ProductWebSiteMappings != null)
{
    await _productWebSiteMappingRepository.DeleteRangeAsync(product.ProductWebSiteMappings.ToList(), ct);
    product.ProductWebSiteMappings = request.ProductWebSiteMappings.Select(s => new ProductWebSiteMapping()
    {
        WebSite = s.WebSite,
        ProductId = product.Id
    }).ToList();
}
```

The questions are, it's correct to do so, or it's best just to load the main entity then performing a delete on the related where the ProductId is equals to the one of the Product?
Also I think that here multiple single delete are done, since the implementation of DeleteAsync is

```cs
public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(TEntity entity, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    if (await IsExistsAsync(entity.Id, ct))
    {
        _context.Remove(entity);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception($"Entity with id {entity.Id} not found!");
    }
}
```

and the DeleteRangeAsync is

```cs
public async Task DeleteRangeAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        await DeleteAsync(entity, ct);
    }
}
```

At the end a call to the    `await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync(ct);` is done

Any suggestion on how to optimize that?

Comment: Why delete/insert? An update is generally better since no PK is involved (reindex/statistic/etc). DeleteAsync function can be a void return since is always true or an exception. Missing the `IsExitsAsync` definition. Why do you raise an exception when you have not found an entity (already deleted?)  and you should delete it?  Have you a concurrency problem?

Comment: EF Core doesn't need any "repository" classes. A DbSet is already a single-entity repository, a DbContext is already a multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work. All client-side changes are tracked in memory and persisted in a single transaction when `SaveChanges` is called *at the end* to *commit the Unit of Work*. Simply modifying an object's property is enough to track it as Modified.

Comment: Is the real question how to persist the `Category` data in `request.Categories` ? If this collection contains `ProductCategory` objects you can call [DbContext.Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-7.0) on each one. EF will start tracking all entities with a non-default primary key as Modified, all those with a default PK as Added

Comment: If `request.Categories` uses a different type and/or you want to update specific properties only, you can create a new `ProductCategory` instance, *attach it as unmodified* with [Attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-7.0) and then mark the modified properties, eg `context.Entry(myEntity).Property(e => e.Age).IsModified = true;`. This works since [EF Core 3](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7370) at least

Comment: so this is an existing code and I think there're a lot of issue in how access to data is managed, in this particular case, starting from @max I think it I'll create an overload wich doesn't look for existence before deleting and delete without trhowing an exception... I don't know if in the past there where concuccrency problems... maybe since this monolith evolved during years and from different hands.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos on this I partially agree with you, all the application is structured with repository pattern, and in this particular app, it uses a weird IUnitOfWork where it just peforms the Save since the dbContext is Transient and injected in the repository classes.

For the second question... I think they delete and reinsert since in this way they're sure no "zombies" remains but I know that doing so there's a reindex issue and so on... if I just call the DbContext.Update what happens on entities that's on db and not in the requested item? I think they remain, while I need to remove